# Reuse custom UITableViewCell, how to get text of each cell's textfield to save?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` whose Nib has a label, a seperator and a `textfield` (very much like the contact app phone number cell).

I have a detail tableview which uses this custom cell for a lot of rows. I do a switch case through sections and rows to set the cell's label and textfield place holder programatically. I want to set the textfields text to my `NSManagedObject` properties in the `ViewWillDisappear`. What's the best way to capture the text in the textfields of the custom cells in different rows/sections?

Comment: add some code for reference

Comment: add some reference code, so can look through detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the controller as delegate of the textfields and set different tag on each field, I was then able to set the text value of the fields to my `NSMangedObjects` attributes via the `textFieldDidEndEditing` protocol.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i  inSection:0];
        customTableCell *cell = (customTableCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
        NSString *textFieldVal = [cell.textLabel text];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you set textField tag of `indexpath.row`

```
UITableViewCell *theCellSelected = [tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row  inSection:0]];

resultlabl = (UITextField*)[theCellSelected.contentView viewWithTag:your_tag_number];
```